# NSwag For ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, openapi, nswag

I would like to use **NSwag** for generating **OpenApi v3 Spec** for ServiceStack(SS) based application. With SS, the contracts are defined in DTO type class and the implementations in another class making it completely decoupled.

```
[Route("/hello", "GET", Summary = @"Default hello service.", Notes = "Longer description for hello services")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}", "GET", Summary = @"Additional hello service", Notes="Longer description for hello services")]
public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "Name", Description = "Name Description",
        ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    [ApiAllowableValues("Name", typeof(string))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

I need to generate the Spec file for the above code. I tried to pass the type of the class `Hello` to the `JsonSchemaGenerator` (by following the `TypesToOpenApiCommand` code) and it did generate the specfile but contains only the component section.

```
"{\"openapi\":\"3.0.0\",\"info\":{\"title\":\"Swagger specification\",\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"servers\":[{\"url\":\"http:///\"}],\"components\":{\"schemas\":{\"Hello\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"additionalProperties\":false,\"properties\":{\"Name\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true}}},\"HelloResponse\":{\"type\":\"object\",\"additionalProperties\":false,\"properties\":{\"Result\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true}}}}}}"
```

Other sections like `paths`, `parameters` were not filled in. Below is the code I used for generating the spec file,

```
var modelAssemblies = LoadFromAssemblies
            .Where(assembly => assembly.FullName != null && assembly.FullName.Contains(".ServiceModel"));

        var types = modelAssemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());

        var document = CreateDocument();

        var generatorSettings = new JsonSchemaGeneratorSettings {SchemaType = SchemaType.OpenApi3};
        var generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(generatorSettings);
        var schemaResolver = new OpenApiSchemaResolver(document, generatorSettings);

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            generator.Generate(type, schemaResolver);
        }
        var json = document.ToJson();
        var yaml = document.ToYaml();
      
        return document;
```

How do I get those sections filled in? Can I get some design ideas on how to proceed forward with my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

For an example on accessing ServiceStack's `HostContext.Metadata` to populate an Open API spec checkout the ServiceStack's [OpenApiServices.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Api.OpenApi/OpenApiService.cs).